# Why are members who have renewed their membership still getting reminders?

Tags: civimember, scheduled-reminders

I have a scheduled job to send out membership reminders.  The job executes fine, people get their reminders and pay up for next year

However, next time the scheduled job runs the people who have renewed still get the renewal reminder.

I know this used to work ok but the past couple of years I can't seem to get it to work the way it used to.  I've had a look at lots of similar sorts of questions but I cant really understand what I'm doing wrong

Is there a setting I've got wrong or something I'm missing?

thanks for any suggestions

Comment: What is your scheduled jobs configuration for **Update Membership Status** and **Send Scheduled Reminders**? Also how are your Membership reminders set? Do you have any errors on the mentioned job logs? To check de scheduled job logs navigate to Administer - System Settings - Scheduled jobs and click on View Job Log

Comment: Please include a screenshot of your membership scheduled reminder set up down to just above the content?